# Determinant of Jacobian matrix of a curve using Frenet–Serret formulas

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let
\begin{align}
\gamma:\ [0,\ell]&\longrightarrow\mathbb R^3
\\ s&\longmapsto\gamma(s)=\big(x,y,z\big)(s)
\end{align} be a parametrized by arc-length curve. Suppose $\gamma''(s)\ne0\ \ \forall s$. Let
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{rccl}T(s)&=&\gamma'(s)&=&\big(t_1,t_2,t_3\big)(s)
\\ N(s)&=&\displaystyle\frac{1}{\|T'(s)\|}T'(s)&=&\big(n_1,n_2,n_3\big)(s)
\\ B(s)&=&T(s)\times N(s)&=&\big(b_1,b_2,b_3\big)(s)
\end{array} 
\end{align}
Consider the $C^1-$diffeomorphism
\begin{align}
\varphi:\ D\subset\mathbb R^3&\longrightarrow\mathbb R^3
\\ (u,v,s)&\longmapsto\varphi(u,v,s)=\gamma(s)+uN(s)+vB(s)
\end{align}
This diffeomorphism brings the curve $\gamma$ to a stright line. I want to find its Jacobian matrix $\,J_\varphi(u,s,v)$, and then evaluate its determiant. But when I wrote out the cordinates of $\varphi$
\begin{align}
\varphi(u,v,s)=\begin{bmatrix}x(s)+\displaystyle\frac{u}{\big\|T'(s)\big\|}x'(s)+\displaystyle\frac{v}{\big\|T'(s)\big\|}\big(y'z''-y''z'\big)(s)
\\ y(s)+\displaystyle\frac{u}{\big\|T'(s)\big\|}y'(s)+\displaystyle\frac{v}{\big\|T'(s)\big\|}\big(z'x''-z''x'\big)(s)
\\ z(s)+\displaystyle\frac{u}{\big\|T'(s)\big\|}z'(s)+\displaystyle\frac{v}{\big\|T'(s)\big\|}\big(x'y''-x''y'\big)(s)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
I found it was quite complicated to calculate the derrivative with respect to $s$.

So is there another easier and more convenient way to calculate the Jacobian or its determinant ? I was guided to use the Frenet–Serret formulas
\begin{align}
T'(s)&=\kappa(s)N(s)
\\ N'(s)&=-\kappa(s)T(s)+\tau(s)B(s)
\\ B'(s)&=-\tau(s)N(s)
\end{align}
but I have no idea how to use it for this problem. Could someone give help me to handle it ? Thank you.

Comment: Don't write things out in terms of components. You have $\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u} = N$, $\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial v} = B$, and $\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial s} = T+u(-\kappa T + \tau B) + v(-\tau N)$. Can you tell when these three vectors are linearly independent? What precise statement can you make? Your claim that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism is certainly not valid in general.

Comment: I have used the Frenet-Serret formulas to find $J_\varphi$ with respect to $T,N,B$, and then evaluated its determinant and obtained $|J_\varphi|=(1-uk)T\cdot(N\times B)$. 
But I just doing all out by totally evaluating the determinant without any tricks, and the calculation was quite long. Is there any tricks to solve the determinant of this matrix easierly ?

Comment: Just do the triple scalar product of the three partial derivatives as I wrote them. You get exactly what you wrote in your comment. If you recall that $N\times B = T$ then it should take literally five seconds to finish.

Comment: you meant $N\times B=-T$, not $T$ ?

Comment: It doesn't affect the problem at hand, but no, I didn't mean that :P